# The About Me dialog doesn't save information

Tags: user-profile

I just installed a fresh copy of 11.04 and have been setting up my preferences.  I have noticed while doing this that the About Me dialog does not save anything that I put in.  I can totally fill the dialog out, close it, and when I reopen it, it is blank.  What is going on?  I have never had any trouble like this out of any of the other Ubuntu versions prior to 11.04.

Comment: [Bug in Evolution](http://askubuntu.com/a/41704/169736)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known Bug in 11.04 (Natty) as filed [in Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/773063).
Apparently this behaviour is due to a lack of an Evolution adress book and a fix is described [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/773063/comments/10), though this probably will be fixed permanently at some point.